# Meaning of p(q) in the expression for minimum clearance from obstacle for redundant robotic manipulators

Tags: robotic-arm, inverse-kinematics, manipulator, jacobian

Can somebody who has studied Industrial manipulators or has worked on Industrial manipulators using Jacobian Inverse and Jacobian Pseudo inverse algorithm for Inverse Kinematics please explain what does p(q) stand for in the following expression. This is used to maximize the minimum clearance from an obstacle for a redundant robotic manipulator, thank you.[image]

Comment: It is hard to say without more context.  Where did you see this equation?  Is there any more info?

Comment: Ok, well actually it is from the ppt which my Master's professor has shared with all the students but yes one can find this in the book - Robotics: Modelling, Planning and Control by B. Siciliano, L. Sciavicco, L. Villani, G. Oriolo. I guess one can find it on springer, we have access to it through our university online library and our professor makes his ppts using this textbook as reference material.